# Ensuring Consistent Mappings Across Multiple Elasticsearch Indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating Elasticsearch indices dynamically with customized mappings and analyzers. I'm facing an issue where the mapping of the index is not consistent with the predefined mappings when the number of indices are above 100.

I want to ensure that the same mapping is created even after creating a large number of indices. Here are the key details of my setup:

1.I am explicitly defining mappings during index creation.

2.I've explored using index templates to enforce mappings across indices.

Despite these efforts, the mappings are not consistent beyond a certain number of indices.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and what steps can I take to ensure that Elasticsearch consistently applies the specified mappings across all dynamically created indices?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing, even after 1000 indices. Can you describe what kid of inconsistencies you're noticing?